# Drag and drop between WPF and winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, drag-and-drop

We have a WPF user control that provides drag and drop functionality. We’ve also used an adorner to provide visual drag/drop feedback to the user about the framework element being dragged. If the hosting application for our user control is WPF, we can drag from the user control and drop to the target control that is hosted in the WPF form and we see the adorner. We have no issues with this scenario.

However, we have an issue because we need this WPF user control to be inside a VB.NET windows form. For our Windows Form project, We added a reference to the WindowsIntegration assembly and added a WPF control inside an ElementHost.  This works great and we can drag and drop but the one issue we can’t solve is that when we drag from the user control to the target element hosted in the VB.NET windows form, the adorner doesn’t show.

Please help!

Comment: Where is the adorned being drawn? In the WPF control, or on the target, or on the window?

Comment: it is drawn in the WPF user control.